# How to set the process title without 3rd library in Python?

Tags: python, linux, ps

A lot of implementations employ 3rd library, such as setproctitle. So can we implement the functionality manually?

Answer (score 0):

Of course, this functionality can be implemented by the Python raw approach. As we all know, Python has the standard library `ctypes`. By using this library, we can do the syscall. Meanwhile, other implementations are the same as to call system function to achieve the objective.

As the code below shows:

```py
        import ctypes
        libc = ctypes.CDLL('libc.so.6')
        progname = ctypes.c_char_p.in_dll(libc, '__progname_full')  # refer to the source code of glibc
        with open('/proc/self/cmdline') as fp:
            old_progname_len = len(fp.readline())
        if old_progname_len > len(new_name):
            # padding blank chars
            new_name += b' ' * (old_progname_len - len(new_name))

        # for `ps` command:
        # Environment variables are already copied to the Python program zone.
        # We can get environment variables by using `os.environ`,
        # hence we can ignore both reallocation and movement.
        libc.strcpy(progname, ctypes.c_char_p(new_name))
        # for `top` command and `/proc/self/comm`:
        buff = ctypes.create_string_buffer(len(new_name) + 1)
        buff.value = new_name
        libc.prctl(15, ctypes.byref(buff), 0, 0, 0)
```